# Unable to retrieve data with RestKit because class is not key value coding compliant

Tags: restkit, tastypie

I am writing a simple Multiple choice question for iOS.

I want to create an API so that I can retrieve the questions and store the answers of the users. I use django and tastypie for the backend.

I use this function to load the quesion in my app :

```
- (void)loadQuestion
{
RKObjectMapping* questionMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Question class]];
[questionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"question": @"question",
 }];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:questionMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"question" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/question/2/?format=json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSLog(@"request : %@", request);
RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Articles: %@", mappingResult.array);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
}];

[objectRequestOperation start];
}
```

Here is my question.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Question : NSObject

@property (strong) NSString *question;

@end
```

And my question.m

```
@implementation Question

@synthesize question = _question;

@end
```

The JSON is the following :

```
{
"chapter": "/api/v1/chapter/2/", 
"id": 2, "
pub_date": "2013-04-25T19:23:42.930097", 
"question": "Quelle est la capitale de ce pays : Emirats Arabes Unis ?", 
"resource_uri": "/api/v1/question/2/"
}
```

And the tastypie API is :

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie import fields

from .models import Question, Chapter

class ChapterResource(ModelResource):
class Meta:
    queryset = Chapter.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'chapter'

class QuestionResource(ModelResource):
chapter = fields.ForeignKey(ChapterResource, 'chapter')

class Meta:
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'question'
```

The error i get is :
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x76b3030> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key question.'

I read https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping but did not find what I am doing wrong.

What is wrong with my class ?

Comment: What JSON is returned?

Comment: @Wain the JSON is : {
"chapter": "/api/v1/chapter/2/", 
"id": 2, "
pub_date": "2013-04-25T19:23:42.930097", 
"question": "Quelle est la capitale de ce pays : Emirats Arabes Unis ?", 
"resource_uri": "/api/v1/question/2/"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning on trace logging to get more details about what's happening with the mapping:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

That said, I'm not sure it's a problem with the mapping. The exception is thrown while trying to read the question from a string object.  RestKit shouldn't be doing that based on your use case. So, you need to add a breakpoint on all exceptions so you can see the full stack trace and work out what's going on: [Xcode adding an exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html).

Looking at your JSON and mapping spec it seems ok.